# How to pull logs for open source projects (Lucene, HTTPClient, jackrabbit, etc.)

Tags: git, version-control, lucene, commit

I want to get the commit logs for these open source projects. I want the actual source code for each commit, the commit messages, time, etc. for the entire duration of the open source project. I want to be able to parse this and create a neat csv. How can I get access to this data?

Answer (score 0):

git log --pretty with a user specified format will let you extract the things you want in a format that might be more easily parsed later.

Comment: I'm kind of a noob to this. So let's take a look at this: https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr , I can access the git logs through terminal and save the output? And these logs give me all the information regarding source code at that point in time, commit messages, time, etc. ?

Comment: Yes, the easiest thing to do is just do a git log <branchName>, so you need to know the branch that you want to trace back or --all if you want on all branches.

Answer (score 0):

what i can infer from your description is that you want a complete history of the commits on that branch. You can simply do :

```
git log
```

which would show you recent commits along with the date and author of that commit. if you do `git show {SHA1}` of any commit it would show you the changes that were made by that commit.
If you do a `git log --stat` it would show you the files that were changed by that commit. git log is an extremely powerful utility with a vast set of options.You can also do :
`git log --oneline --decorate --graph --pretty` to see nice merge history of commits.

You said you want to parse that data into a csv. I hope this can help you:

```
git log --pretty=format:"%cn, %h, %cd, %s"
```